# Configure switch in GNS3

Tags: voip, gns3, telephony

Is there any way to configure a switch in GNS3?

Comment: Removed the off-topic questions about applications and host configuration.

Comment: What version of GNS3 are you running?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is only ways of configuring other types of network devices.